# How to disable angular.reloadWithDebugInfo() from browser console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want app scope variables should not be accessible from the browser console.
I used `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`

However that can be manipulated using `reloadWithDebugInfo()`.

How do I make app scope variables should not be accessible during production?

Comment: "scope variables should not be accessible during production?" -> Impossible.

Comment: You send javascript to user's browser and it means the user and their computer are in control of the data there.

Answer (score 0):

I know its would be hacky solution

You could make `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo` to override with blank function.

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo = angular.noop
```